# Javascript Function to Remove Div

Tags: javascript, html

I need a function that can delete the div one by one .
My code is shown below. in my code i have created a function to create a div when i click a button . and i can't figure how to delete div one by one .

Please help me with the correct code to delete div one by one.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<button id="buttonone" onclick="creatediv()">CREATE A DIV</button>
<button id="buttontwo" onlick="removedivider()">Remove DIV </button>
<script>




function creatediv()
{

document.getElementById("buttonone").innerHTML="CREATE ANOTHER DIV";    

var newdiv = document.createElement("div");
newdiv.setAttribute("id","newdiv");
var text = document.createTextNode(Math.floor(Math.random()*100)+1); 
newdiv.appendChild(text);
newdiv.style.color="white";
newdiv.style.width="100px";
newdiv.style.backgroundColor="green";

document.body.appendChild(newdiv);

}


function removedivider()
{
    //Function to Remove the DIV one by one;
}


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So, you're just going to keep appending divs with the same `id`?

Comment: Do you want a `remove` button on each div or a button that just removes `div`s one by one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your code with the following

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>DIVs</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

function create_div() {
  document.getElementById("button1").innerHTML="CREATE ANOTHER DIV";    
  var div = document.createElement("DIV");
  var text = document.createTextNode(Math.floor(Math.random()*100)+1); 
  div.appendChild(text);
  div.style.color = "white";
  div.style.width = "100px";
  div.style.backgroundColor = "green";
  document.body.appendChild(div);
}

function remove_div() {
  var div = document.getElementsByTagName('DIV'), i;
  for(i = div.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
     div[i].parentNode.removeChild(div[i]);
     return false;
  }
}

</script>
</head>
<body>

    <button id="button1" onclick="create_div()">CREATE DIV</button>
    <button id="button2" onclick="remove_div()">REMOVE DIV</button>

</body>
</html>
```

By the way, you can't have multiple DIVs having the same ID. Check the working [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/hinaroro/1/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
var index = 0;
function creatediv()
{
++index;
document.getElementById("buttonone").innerHTML="CREATE ANOTHER DIV";    

var newdiv = document.createElement("span");
newdiv.setAttribute("id","newdiv" + index);
var text = document.createTextNode(Math.floor(Math.random()*100)+1); 
newdiv.appendChild(text);
newdiv.style.color="white";
newdiv.style.width="100px";
newdiv.style.backgroundColor="green";

document.body.appendChild(newdiv);
}


function removedivider()
{
    document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById("newdiv" + index));
    --index;
}
</script>
```

Should work, I didn't test.

Answer (score 1):

You weren't very clear regarding which `div` should be removed. Also, in your code, you repeatedly appended `div`s with the same `id`. You can't do that.

I made a quick example that removes the `div` appended first (a queue). I gave each date an `id` based on the current time, but such isn't really necessary. You could always just remove the first child of the parent div to which you are appending these `div`s.

However, if you plan on appending these `div`s in places that are not necessarily all under the same parent, then giving them unique `id`s and storing said `id`s is useful.

## [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Luxelin/24Lmp/4/)

**HTML**

```
<button id="add">add</button>
<button id="remove">remove</button>
<div id="holder">
    <p>Added divs will go here</p>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var ids = [];

document.getElementById("add").onclick = function () {
    var id = new Date().getTime(),    // generate unique id (sort of)
        div = document.createElement("div");  // create a div element

    ids.push(id);    // push the generated id to the holder array, ids
    div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(id));  // append a text node to the div
    div.setAttribute("class", "newDiv");    // give it a class for styling
    div.setAttribute("id", id);    // set its id
    
    document.getElementById("holder").appendChild(div); // append the div
}

document.getElementById("remove").onclick = function () {
    if (ids.length) {    // only perform if a div has been appended
        var div = document.getElementById(ids.shift());
        // ids.shift() removes and returns ids[0], or the earliest added div
        // this finds that element in the DOM
        div.parentNode.removeChild(div);    // and removes it
    } else {    // otherwise alert that there are no divs to remove
        alert("no divs to remove!");
    }
}
```

**CSS**

```
.newDiv {
    height: 20px;
    width: 110px;
    background-color: #7EA8CA;
    border: solid 1px #93CC76;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This function assumes there will be no other div elements. It will also remove the divs in fifo order.

```
function removedivider() {
    var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
    if (divs.length > 0) divs[0].remove();
}
```

**EDIT:**

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BWL47/)

Comment: I am not sure why, but in order to get the button onclick event handlers to work I had to declare them inline. See the edit for this answer.